# How do I make my mousecursor change when I hover over images?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make a button with an image where when I click on the image a sound plays.

It works fine but here is the problem, when I hover over the image the cursor doesn't change.

It is probaly some simple things I need to change in the style document.

Comment: Please post some code for which you have done.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: img:hover {cursor:pointer;} for example  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Answer (score 2):

You can change the cursor with the cursor css property. See below link.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

An example

```
img:hover{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use inline css to get the pointer

```
<img src = "image_url_here" style = "cursor: pointer"/>
```

Comment: He asksed to change the pointer only on mouse hover. Also it is not recommended to use inline css.